# How do find the mysqldump operation permission by that user

Tags: mysql

How to do i find the a user has grant permission for mysqldump ?

Comment: Do you want to have a list of users who may use mysqldump?

Comment: AFAIK, any user has the SELECT privilege will do (for normal select operations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need SELECT and LOCK privileges for any database/table you are dumping, so execute this statement to get the list of users having these privileges:

> `SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE select_priv AND Lock_tables_priv='Y';`